# Why doesn't Xcode suggest @synchronized?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autocomplete, mutex

I only rarely use @synchronized, but as far as I can remember (meaning around Xcode 3.2 or something), it never suggested @synchronized when using the auto-completion, and still never does.
I do get suggestions when typing '@', like @autorelease, @encode, @selector and so forth.

Is there any known reason for this ? I wasn't able to find any related topic. It's been bugging me, because it gives me the feeling that this is not a valid method to handle concurrency in iOS.

Comment: Pretty sure its still valid. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW3

Answer (score 0):

@synchronized does not appear when using auto-completion because Apple has not mapped that keyword to any code sense implementation.
Per Apple's suggestion, I have filed a bug report.

However, I can offer an auto-complete solution.
You may create an @synchronized snippet that can be auto-completed or drag and dropped into your code.

1. Copy/paste the code below into one of your Xcode documents.
2. Select the new code and drag it to your snippets library.
3. Double-click the new snippet and click edit.
4. Enter @synchronized for the completion shortcut.

For more info: http://nshipster.com/xcode-snippets/

```
@synchronized(anObj) {
    // Everything between the braces is protected by the @synchronized directive.
}
```